# How to set date format in bipublisher to specific region? Like Kuwait time region. Format will be like : 12-Jan-2018

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, bi-publisher

How to set date format in Bi Publisher to specific region? 
Like Kuwait time region.
Format will be like : 12-Jan-2018.
I was used 
but its showing like, 2015-aug-17 with time. 
DD-Mon-YYYY: This one I have tried already, but getting less than a day in report.

Comment: What did you try and how did you try. Please add that as well in your question

Comment: I was tried : **<?format-date:START_DATE;'DD-MON-YYYY'?>** in date column. But it's showing less than a day. 
Expected: **15-Sep-2015**
Result: **14-Sep-2015 21:00:00** 
@XING

Comment: Are you sure there is data for `15-Sep-2015`. Can you check once.

Comment: Yes, It was there in seeded output(XML).

Comment: Hi @XING any updates?

Comment: What is the value which is in the XML for the START_DATE?